# inserting to SqlLite takes too long by django

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, bigdata

hello i have 26 file (each ~100MB) i try to inserting by this view :

```
def index(request):
    url = '../xaa'
    count = 0
    line_num = 1660792
    start = time.time()
    for lines in fileinput.input([url]):
            user = ast.literal_eval(lines)
            T.objects.create(a=user['a'], b=user['b'], c=user['c'])
            count += 1
            percent = (100 * count) / line_num
            print(f"{percent}%")

    end = time.time()
    print(f"Time : {end - start}%")
    response = HttpResponse('Done')
    return response
```

but it's take too long (3.5 day for a file) how can i do it faster ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading 1.66 million lines one by one and creating model instances one by one in your code. There are sever issues with what you are doing:

Firstly you create each object **one by one**, this means one query for creating **each** object! That is 1.66 million queries! If that doesn't take time then what will? Next you make a print in each iteration, although this may not be noticeable in small programs a print also takes a substantial amount of time, with the amount of prints you are making you are just slowing down your program.

If you want to create many objects in bulk you can use the [`bulk_create` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) method, although given that you have so many lines perhaps you should do this in batches:

```py
def index(request):
    url = '../xaa'
    count = 0
    batch_size = 100 # Will insert each 100th time
    line_num = 1660792
    start = time.time()
    batch_list = []
    for lines in fileinput.input([url]):
        if count % batch_size == 0:
            T.objects.bulk_create(batch_list)
            batch_list = []
        user = ast.literal_eval(lines)
        batch_list.append(T(a=user['a'], b=user['b'], c=user['c']))
        count += 1
        # Forego printing
        # percent = (100 * count) / line_num
        # print(f"{percent}%")
    if batch_list: # If any objects remaining
        T.objects.bulk_create(batch_list)
        batch_list = []
    end = time.time()
    print(f"Time : {end - start}%")
    response = HttpResponse('Done')
    return response
```

Moving forward it appears your file is in some format like JSON Lines. You can look into the documentation for [Providing data with fixtures [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/initial-data/#providing-data-with-fixtures). These fixtures support the JSON Lines from Django 3.2 onwards (See [Serialization formats [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/serialization/#serialization-formats)). You may have to modify your files a little to fit the structure expected by these fixtures but then you can leave this loading to the command [`loaddata` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#loaddata)